# Merging polygons to new shapefile with sum of total area using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, area, overlapping-features

I am trying to group some polygons of a shapefile into a new one (with one record) but I want to maintain their total sum area. Some of them are overlapping. When I try Merge from Editor, the new total area is not the sum that I want.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried the Select followed by Dissolve tools?

Comment: First assign unique id field for your groups, compute their areas in a separate field and use later as statistics field with unique being case field.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with shapefiles, you will have to recalculate the area after the Merge tool, as ArcMap doesn't automatically calculate it, like it does for geodatabases. To do that, you will need to [Calculate Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm). Noting that area will be in the units of your coordinate system - so ensure you're using a projected coordinate system.

Alternatively, as PolyGeo's comment states, you could try the [Dissolve](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool with a selection of your features (or a definition query on your layer). You will set the statistics option to **`SUM`** of your area field.

Comment: This is not his issue, keyword is overlap.